# Манипуляции с регистрами общего назначения в x64

Tags: ассемблер, x86-64

Имеется регистр общего назначения, скажем RAX. В нем лежит значение :
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. Я хочу занулить младшие 32 бита. На ум соответственно приходят следующие варианты:

```
xor EAX,EAX
mov EAX,0
and EAX,0
```

Только проблема в том, что после выполнения любой из этих операций старшие 32 бита RAX также зануляются. Т.е. в RAX имеем вместо значения 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 значение 0x0000000000000000.
Рабочий вариант зануления -

```
shr,32
shl,32
```

Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и чем она обусловлена?

Comment: у вас 64 бита архитектура? а кто вам сказал что EAX имеет размер 32 бита?

Comment: Америкосы спрашивали и им отвечали, что тонкости работы процессора мешает эффективно работать, проще забить нулями.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455447/x86-64-registers-rax-eax-ax-al-overwriting-full-register-contents

Comment: Владимир Клыков, а какая по-вашему размерность EAX? )